# React-native-navigation tab bar center circle icon

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

How do I make the tab bar in the center of the circle with a custom icon like this image?
I am using react-native-navigation.

[image: click for image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android overflow is no effect,but you can use position, you can make like that.
https://github.com/wuyunqiang/RNApp